# Spring 4 and VelocityEngineFactoryBean

Tags: spring, velocity

Hi? Can you help me? Where now is VelocityEngineFactoryBean for spring 4? I can't find needed dependency. I looked over `spring-support` and `spring-context-support`, but there is no result.

Answer (score 1):

`VelocityEngineFactoryBean` class is there in the `spring-context-support` jar.

Add the following dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

You can check the files contained in this jar using the following command from your command prompt

```
jar tf  C:\Users\user0007\Desktop\spring-context-support-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar
```